# SSIS unable to see data

Tags: excel, ssis

I tried to import data from excel spreadsheet to OLEDB and it showed the green ticks which indicated the import took successfully. But when I checked the MS SQL Server destination table, I cannot see any data. I also checked my excel files and they have the data.

[image]

Comment: Check the configuration of the OLE DB Destination (connection properties, etc.). Determine what the warning is on your Destination component - it may be that you have not mapped the columns.  If you need help, post screenshots of each tab in your OLE DB Destination.

Comment: Showing a green tick indicates the component passed runtime verification. To verify whether there are rows delivered in the pipeline, could you enable data viewer and check whether there are rows? And though it is a low chance case, can you check your destination table to ensure there is no instead trigger (as I had this scenario before)

Comment: Check your destination mappings.

Comment: Sounds silly, but also check that you are querying the right server.